# Replace the real value from api for parameter in the URL when changing manually by the user in the address bar using Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Lets say, I have the url,

`http://localhost:4200/param1/param2/product`

Here param1, param2 are the parameter real values from api. If the user changes the value of parameter in the address bar manually and reloading the page. The value of the parameter should be replaced by the real values(param1, param2) from the api. Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Comment: you can use session storage if you want that to persist over the redirection or Url change

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) route guard.
In the guard action you'll check the api result, and you can redirect if needed.

Here is a simple code for checking the parameter that the user typed in the url.
Of-coarse you can validate this parameter by calling your api.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  const idParam: number = +next.paramMap.get('id');
  if (idParam === 3) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/hello/1');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

> Here is a [Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-routing-guard) to show you the idea (notice the url).

Comment: CanActivate is a route guard which is useful to provide authentication for certain users. But here we can use this url for both anonymous or non-anonymous user. Here I am trying to change the param value of route from api if user entered wrong value.

Comment: I don't know where you've got the idea that guards are for authentication only, this is not true, you can use them for any logic you need. I'll update my answer to let you have an idea of my solution for you.

Comment: Please update your answer with some more explanation to understand clearly about the implementation.